# Eigenvalues and their negatives, example from Friedberg

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've found two examples in Friedberg's Linear Algebra book that confused me.

He shows a Diagonal Matrix with Diagonal Entries $3, 1, -3$ (after reducing). And he refers to the eigenvalues as -1 and 3. But isn't there also -3?

For another Matrix with diagonals -1 1 and 3 he has Eigenvalues 1 and 3. But isn't there also an Eigenvalue -1?

From the Characteristic equation i get $(3 - t)(1-t)(-3 - t) = 0$. So there are three distinct roots in my opinion? Could somebody explain this to me? I'm super confused. Thank you!

Comment: You are correct that there are 3 Eigenvalues for your examples. I don't know the book, but maybe he just wants to show something for the Eigenvalues 3 and 1, and wants you to do the same thing for -3?

Comment: Please include the relevant passage from the book. Also, what do you mean by “after reducing?” The usual process of row reduction (a.k.a. Gaussian elimination) doesn’t preserve eigenvalues.

Comment: @amd thanks. Apologies, though I think the relevant passage adds little info. Therefore the eigenvalues of B are also −1 and 3. But, as we
explain next, the status of the eigenvalues −1 and 3 is different in A and B. But I suspect from your last comment that my deduction on how they got the eigenvalues is wrong. I imagined they got to the equation by gaussian elimination, whcih they probably didn't.

Comment: It’s the preceding parts of the text that would be more useful, I expect. Anyway, row-reducing the original matrix doesn’t get you its eigenvalues, but you can row-reduce $A-\lambda I$ in order to compute its determinant, which gets you the characteristic equation.